# Pass parameter to MySQL script command line

Tags: mysql, cmd

Is there any option to pass a parameter from the command line to MySQL script?

Something like @start_date in this example:

```
mysql –uuser_id -ppassword –h mysql-host -A -e 
"set @start_date=${start_date}; source ${sql_script};" >${data_file};
```

Comment: @Kaii he is most likely looking for something like "scripting variables" that [SQLCMD of SQL Server supports with the `-v` option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Found an answer on the net [here](http://databobjr.blogspot.com/2011/07/passing-parameters-to-mysql-query.html).

Basically, suppose that we want to run this query:

```
Select c_id, c_first_name,c_last_name, c_address,last_modified_date
from customer
where last_modified_date >=@start_date and last_modified_date <= @end_date;
```

We can pass 'start_date' and 'end_date' like this:

```
/usr/bin/mysql –uuser_id -ppassword –h mysql-host -A \
    -e "set @start_date=${start_date}; set @end_date=${end_date};\
        source ${sql_script};" > ${data_file}
```

Comment: It is worth noting that it's the shell which expands this variable so this answer implies a *nix shell.

Comment: But this SQL parameters usage don't protect from SQL injection. So there no advantage over direct include shell var in sql query.

Comment: As pointed out by the other two comments, this is not a parameterized statement and is an absolutely terrible solution to this problem.

Comment: I have opened a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55374938/injection-proof-sql-statements-from-command-line) asking about the security of this.

Answer (score 3):

The Short answer:

bash :

```
        mysql -u"$mysql_user" -p"$mysql_user_pw" \
        -e "set @mysql_db='$mysql_db';source \
        00.create-mysql-starter-db.mysql ;" > "$tmp_log_file" 2>&1
```

mysql:

```
     SET @query = CONCAT('CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `'
     , @mysql_db , '` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */') ; 
     -- SELECT 'RUNNING THE FOLLOWING query : ' , @query ; 
      PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
      EXECUTE stmt;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

The Long answer : 
The whole concept as a runnable bash , mysql app :

https://github.com/YordanGeorgiev/mysql-starter

or

```
    git clone git@github.com:YordanGeorgiev/mysql-starter.git
```

Comment: what is that 00. ? before the sql file name

Answer (score 0):

The "-e" option is sensible to the used quotes, try the double quote:

```
mysql –uuser_id -ppassword –h mysql-host -A -e 
"set @start_date=\"$start_date\"; source \"$sql_script\";" >\"$data_file\";"
```

Answer (score -1):

You may be able to avoid bash code in some cases by composing scripts together to run SQL code with different predefined arguments.

For example:

`do-something-production.sql`

```
USE mydb-prod;
SET @arg=5;
SOURCE do-something.sql;
```

`do-something-test.sql`:

```
USE mydb-test;
SET @arg=10;
SOURCE do-something.sql;
```

`do-something.sql`:

```
UPDATE table SET col = (SELECT @arg);
```