# parameter to mysql source file ant script

Tags: mysql, ant

I want to pass parameters to mysql source file from ant script.

Here is my ant script.

```
<target name="post"
        description="do post processing command: -Dusername=db-username -Dpassword=db-password -Ddb=database-name post">
        <echo message="Doing Post processing..."></echo>
        <sql driver="org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://${dburl}/kom?autoReconnect=true"
            userid="userid" password="password" print="yes" classpathref="class-path"
            src="${sql-dir}/${post-sql}" output="logs/ant-sql.log">
        </sql>
    </target>
```

In the sql file, I have to do the following..

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $(dbname);
use $(dbname);

-- create table posts 
-- a lot of create and insert statemenst.
```

I can't use mysql console or any other utilities.

Can somebody tell me how to do this ?

### Solution

I moved the use $(dbname) from sql file to ant script.

```
<target name="post"
        description="do post processing command: -Dusername=db-username -Dpassword=db-password -Ddb=database-name post">
        <echo message="Doing Post processing..."></echo>
        <sql driver="org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://${dburl}/kom?autoReconnect=true"
            userid="root" password="tintin" print="yes" classpathref="class-path"
            src="${sql-dir}/${post-sql}" output="logs/ant-sql.log">
            use ${dbname};
        </sql>
</target>
```

It works as a temporary solution.

Comment: You could try a filterset on a copy task and generate a sql file to be used. See: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterset.html

Comment: Are you looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10229324/pass-parameter-to-mysql-script-command-line

Comment: I fixed it myself. I will put the solution.

Comment: @Rao. it will not work for me. I am not using mysql command line client.