# Bash - Use txt to return value from mysql

Tags: mysql, bash

The process is:

1. I have a list of files (that keeps growing)
2. The NAMES of these files are written in a txt file (`filelist.txt`)
3. Each line of this txt will be a query to mysql return an output
4. That output will be written on a txt file (`output_file.txt`)

ie, this is used to rename the files of *1.* .

For example, the first line of txt file is "Yellow". Then it will search "Yellow" on mysql and return "Colour", which will be print on a txt.

My problem is on *3.*.
I'm using synology NAS. The bash code that I'm using to *3.* isn't working:

```
#!/bin/sh

cat /volume1/blabla/filelist.txt | while read line
do
   #check if file exists
   if [ -f $line ] 
   then
        #turn the file into a command
        cmd=$(cat $line)
        mysql -h xx.xxx.xx.xx -u xx -pxx --execute="SELECT xx FROM xx WHERE lastName LIKE '%cmd' " > /volume1/blabla/output_file.txt;   
        fi
done
```

I'm getting:

> sh: -c: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token 'done'
>
> sh: -c: line 10: 'done'

Comment: Your script has a bunch of syntax issues. Copy paste the script in http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to fix the errors shown

Comment: LIKE '%cmd' ?  I doubt that would be replaced by ${cmd}

Comment: The answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10265580/5520354 Also, is the data in the files coming from users? From [little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) maybe?

Comment: @LukStorms Are there any alternatives to do that? I was using "cmd" to read each line of the txt  and use that on the query

Comment: @C14L which data? The filelist.txt is created by other script, that lists the name of each file in that txt

Comment: @blocnt The data in the `filelist.txt` file.

Comment: @blocnt  the way Kenavoz solved it by using the ${line} variable to change the SQL statement.