# Can we add variable names in mysql queries?

Tags: mysql

consider a table.

```
id    count       dates
1      10       2016-11-12
2      20       2016-11-12
3      20       2016-11-12
4      20       2016-11-13
5      20       2016-11-13
6      20       2016-11-14
```

i am creating a test.sql file
which contains

select * from table_name where dates = 2016-11-12;

if i have to find rows for date 2016-11-13 i have to change where condition in my .sql file.

what i want is can i declare a variable name at the top of my .sql or outside my file

which has variable `DateSelect` and i only change that and date in my .sql changes automatically.

for eg.

inside test.sql

```
declare DateSelect = 2016-11-12

select * from table_name where dates = DateSelect;
```

and then i can change DateSelect to whatever i want.

i came across this documentation, but i couldn't understand it fully as i am new to mysql.[Variable substitution in SQL statements](http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/using-variables.html)
Any ideas how do i achieve that, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can by wrapping your query in a stored procedure like

```
create procedure usp_sql(@datevar datetime)
as
begin
select * from table_name where dates = @datevar;
end
```

Then you can call it like

```
call usp_sql('2016-11-12');
```

Per your latest comment, see this existing post [Pass parameter to MySQL script command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10229324/pass-parameter-to-mysql-script-command-line)

Comment: :And can i also give multiple arguments inside usp_sql(__)

Comment: @SRingne, yes absolutely you can ... as many you want

Comment: if i understand you completely , i should save this code as test.sql
so how would use call usp_sql() ?

Comment: @SRingne, how you are trying to call the sql file?

Comment: i would be running it  via `mysql -u username -p database_name < test.sql`   in command line

Comment: @SRingne, see edit in answer and the linked post

Comment: i got another simpler solution [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html](from this link)

Comment: @SRingne, that probably won't work with sql files. test it once.

Answer (score 0):

You may use internal vars using **WbVar** assigns. You just have to assign the value to a variable you want and put that variable in the query. It will take the value you assigned. I hope it helps.