# mysql: passing pwd into sql script

Tags: mysql

I am going to run the following, but need to pass a password into .sql file as well. I am hoping I will read pwd from the some secure file and can pass it in

```
mysql --login-path=db_server ${db} < "/path/to/sql_script/update.sql"
```

Comment: found an answer to my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10229324/pass-parameter-to-mysql-script-command-line

Answer (score 1):

Although the command-line tool will get really upset, it'll still let you supply a password with the `--password=XXXXX` argument. You cannot put it in the `.sql` file.

You can also put the password in a [config file](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html) in your home directory, like `.mylogin.cnf` or `~/my.cnf`

Comment: It's my fault for not stating requirements cleanly. I need to be able to pass a variable (in my case it will be pwd) into .sql script that is being run by mysql. In this case, update.sql contains an update statements:  update T set pwd="PWD". So I'd like to be able to pass PWD value into .sql. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: It's not clear. Do you mean you want to pass in a password for *connecting to the server* or is this just a piece of data you need to insert into the .sql file and execute that on the server?

Comment: this is just a piece of data I need to insert into the .sql file and execute that on the server

Comment: A plain-text file can't do that. You need some kind of script.