# Loading multiple csv files to MariaDB/MySQL through bash script

Tags: mysql, shell, csv, mariadb

After trying for a full day, I'm hoping someone here can help me make below script work. I've combined information from multiple threads ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10229324/pass-parameter-to-mysql-script-command-line)) and websites, but can't get it to work.

---

### What I'm trying to do:

I'm trying to get a MariaDB10 database called 'stock_db' on my Synology NAS to load all *.csv files from a specific folder (where I save downloaded historical prices of stocks) and add these to a table called 'prices'. The files are all equally named "price_history_'[isin](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/i/isin.asp)'.csv".
Below SQL statement works when running it individually from HeidiSQL on my Windows machine:

### Working SQL

```
LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY LOCAL INFILE 'D:\\Downloads\\price_history_NL0010366407.csv'
IGNORE INTO TABLE `stock_db`.`prices`
CHARACTER SET utf8
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
            OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
            ESCAPED BY '"'
            LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
            IGNORE 2 LINES
(@vdate, @vprice)
SET
    isin = 'NL0010366407',
    date = STR_TO_DATE(@vdate, '%d-%m-%Y'),
    price = @vprice
;
```

---

### The issue

Unfortunately, when I try to batch loading all csv's from a folder on my NAS through below script, I keep getting the same error.

```
#!/bin/bash

for filename in ./price_history/*.csv; do
echo $filename
isin=${filename:30:12}
echo $isin
/volume1/@appstore/MariaDB10/usr/local/mariadb10/bin/mysql -u root -p \
    "LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY LOCAL INFILE '$filename'\
    IGNORE INTO TABLE 'stock_db.prices'\
        CHARACTER SET utf8\
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'\
        OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'"'"'\
        ESCAPED BY '"'"'"'\
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'\
        IGNORE 2 LINES (@vdate, @vprice)\
    SET\
        isin = '$isin',\
        date = STR_TO_DATE(@vdate, '%d-%m-%Y'),\
        price = @vprice;"
done
```

> ERROR 1102 (42000): Incorrect database name

---

### What I've tried

- Took the database name out of stock_db.prices and mentioned it separately as [database]  outside of the quoted SQL statement - Doesn't work
- Changed quotes around 'stock_db.prices' in many different ways - Doesn't work
- Separated the SQL into a separate file and referenced it '< stmt.sql' - Complicates things even further and couldn't get it to work at all (although probably preferred)
- Considered (or even preferred) using a PREPARE statement, but seems I can't use this in combination with LOAD DATA ([reference](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/prepare-statement/))

---

### Bonus Question

If someone can help me do this without having to re-enter the user's password or putting the password in the script, this would be really nice bonus!

---

### Update

Got the 'Incorrect Database Error' resolved by adding '-e' option
Now I have a new error on the csv files:

> ERROR 13 "Permission Denied"

While the folder and files are full access for everyone.
Anyone any thoughts to this?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to set database using -D option: change the first line to

   `/volume1/@appstore/MariaDB10/usr/local/mariadb10/bin/mysql -D stock_db -u root -p \ ...`
2. You may have an error in this line `IGNORE INTO TABLE 'stock_db.prices'\` - try to remove the single quotes.
3. Create file .my.cnf in your user's home directory and put the following information into it:

   `[client]
   password="my password"`

   [Info about option files.](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/configuring-mariadb-with-option-files/)

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I'm still getting the same error. I'll investigate those option files a bit more... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
'stock_db.prices'
```

Incorrect quoting.  This will work since neither are keywords:

```
stock_db.prices
```

This will also work:

```
`stock_db`.`prices`
```

Note that the db name and the table name are quoted separately, using backtics.

I can't predict what will happen with this nightmare:

```
'"'"'"'
```