# using the question mark in command line MySQL

Tags: mysql, command-line, prepared-statement

I have searched and searched this and only found information for MySQL variables, which is not what I want. What I do want is to run the same SQL from my PHP that I do from the command line, that means providing input to the SQL script/file

I've tried:

```
mysql -u root -p dev < page.sql '/';
mysql -u root -p dev < page.sql /;

etc
```

or basically

```
mysql -u root -p dev < page.sql 'My Title';
```

where the file is

```
select * from content where id=?
```

I've run this from the command line successfully:

```
mysql -u root -p dev < content.sql
```

content.sql:

```
select * from content
```

but I cant get it done with the parameter, I'm doing this because I'm using PHP's PDO and see no reason why I shouldn't by able to run that sql from the command line. If anyone could help me I'd appreciate it, I've already set my env var and file privilege, Thanks...

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: AFAIK, there's no way to do query parameters in the command line.

Comment: They can only be used from the API, or in prepared statements in a procedure.

Comment: The command line does not accept parameterized queries, afaik.

Comment: I wrote a proof of concept in [an answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55381399/20860), but I want to be clear that I would prefer to use some other language like Python or Go if it was required to use query parameters.